# How to generate Listview with button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to implement a listView with three button below. My xml is given by the code below but the problem is the position of button. In the first time I used only linear but in some time the action of buttons are inversed. So I ought to use Relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/retour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Actualise"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="Actualiser la liste" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/testbutton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="@string/selection" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your relative layout below the list view should simply be a linear layout

Comment: I tried this, i will have the button the the listview

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="379dp" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works fine to show listview qith three button below listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```